# I am having some problem with responsiveness

Tags: html, css

I am just re-creating this page (https://appbrewery.github.io/capstone-2-example) with HTML and CSS only.

The top Hero section is responsive in the given link. They didn't use any media query to adjust the responsive.

I have done the same thing, but my one is not responsive, i don't know where it's going wrong.My clouds are moving and when i resize the screen and i can see white space on the right hand side for small devices.
This my git hub link (https://yaswanthkumar7201.github.io/naga-demo/).

Hero section is not responsive as original site, my clouds images are moving and i don't know why the clouds are not moving in appbrewery website after certain max-width.

```
type here
``
    <section class="head-body">
       <img class="top-cloud" src="./images/cloud.png" alt="cloud">
        <h1>I'm Angela.</h1>
        <h2>a <span style="text-decoration: underline;">pro</span>grammer.</h2>
         <img class="bottom-cloud" src="./images/cloud.png" alt="cloud">
        <img src="./images/mountain.png" alt="mountain">
    </section>

``
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0;
    

}

`.head-body{
    background-color:#e4f9f5;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}
h1{
    font-family: "Sacramento", cursive;
    font-size:  5rem;
    color: #66bfbf;
    margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
}

section.head-body img > h1,h2{
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    color: #66bfbf;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.top-cloud{
    position: absolute;
    right: 300px;
    top: 40px;
}
.bottom-cloud{
    position: absolute;
    left: 250px;
    bottom: 300px;
}
`
```

Comment: Try using the code snippet tools to create a working example of your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}

.head-body {
    background-color: #e4f9f5;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 800px; 
    margin: auto;
}

h1 {
    font-family: "Sacramento", cursive;
    font-size: 5vw; 
    color: #66bfbf;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

h2 {
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-size: 2.5vw; 
    color: #66bfbf;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.top-cloud, .bottom-cloud {
    max-width: 100%; 
    height: auto; 
}

.top-cloud {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10%; 
    top: 40px;
}

.bottom-cloud {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10%; 
    bottom: 20%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help i have made small change, from max-width to min with, it worked the way i want.